# Should a user interface be implemented using the Singleton design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, oop

I can't think of many reasons (or any at all) in which multiple independent user interfaces should be instantiated in a desktop application. Is it good practice to implement the UI as a singleton? Are there are advantages or disadvantages to this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uh...i open multiple copies of Internet Explorer, Word, and Excel all the time!

EDIT: I also have several emails open at once in Eudora

I see no good reason to restrict a user-interface to a singleton...

Comment: but are those all the same process? (i honestly don't know). If they aren't, they then it doesn't matter as a singleton is *process* local

Comment: @[Evan Teran]: in a Windows MDI application multiple copies of the same form would be in the same process. For IE/Word/Excel they may be different processes. Singleton scope for applications would imply 'per machine' to me, but Your Mileage May Vary ;-)

Comment: I just opened 3 instances of word 2007 and I see only one winword.exe in my process lsit.

Comment: also, the standard singleton pattern uses static storage to locate the unique instantce, which is per-process (or per appDomain, in .NET), not per-machine

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple:

1) Document interfaces. If your application deals with documents, it's better to let each one have its own window. It makes it easier for the user to arrange their workspace and switch between documents using the OS's app switching capabilities. A lot of MDI applications prevent this by corraling multiple documents into the same window, which limits usability of screen real estate in a multiple monitor scenario.

2) Views. It's often the case that several different views on the data behind your UI cannot be easily combined in a single UI instance. You can't always predict what combinations of data your user will want to see at the same time, so it's better to give them the flexibility to instantiate multiple UIs.

As an aside, it's worth noting that many people consider Singleton an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

What advantage does a singleton give you? Are you aware of the potential problems of this pattern (e.g. multithreading issues with all obvious implementations)?

In practice, if there's no compelling reason to use it, you might want to avoid using the Singleton. For the UI, there isn't actually a compelling reason even if it doesn't get instantiated multiple times.

Comment: Regarding the potential problems, no I'm not fully aware at this stage. I'm still just getting my feet wet in the pool of design patterns. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

A singleton is a global variable. You making it a global encourages you to reference your controls all over your other classes (Imagine your data abstraction layer grabbing a name/addresss pair from the Database, and just for convenience, updating your name/address textbox right there) The resulting code is brittle and the dependencies become hard to resolve. Much easier just to have responsibility limited to a certain subset of classes.

Answer (score 1):

You use a singleton for cases where it's an **error** to have more than one instance of a type of object, not because you can't think of any good reason to have more than one instance.